# Can I transit in Germany without a visa?

Tags: transit, germany, transit-visas, cameroonian-citizens

I'm a Cameroonian by nationality, presently in Turkey. I want to travel to the Philippines and I don't need a visa because we are allowed visa free entry. Will I be allowed to transit in Germany?

Comment: Are you thinking about just changing flights at a German airport, or some more involved transit that you need to go landside for?